Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' has no member 'font'
I am using the current Xcode-Version and in the Build-Settings I have Swift 5. But always get the error of the
Type 'NSAttributedString.Key' has no member 'font'

This are the imports:
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

and in this Code I like to use the attributes

static func createContentPage(for report: CustomerOrderWorkReports, size: CGSize) -> PDFPage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            
            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 72)
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
            paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 5.0

            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
            
            var text = "Datum: \(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: report.addDate ?? Date(), dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none))\n"
            text += "Positions and worktime:\n"


            text.draw(with: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: size.width - 40, height: size.height - 40), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        }

        return PDFPage(image: img)
    }

But always get the error, that I had written. with the paragraphStyle, the error is the same. Also I had restarted Xcode and always erased the simulator.
The build be successfully and the Text would be added to the PDF-File.
But the error still stay.
Restarted Xcode and also the Computer.

Related: Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'font'

If it builds successfully, what's the problem?

You are right, i can let it so and live always with the notification of the error. But isn't that a clean code, when get always the error? I read so much that it depends on swift 3 and have to switch to swift 4, but i habe Swift 5 in the project.
